# The Theorem of Hadamard and de la Vallée-Poussin

Tags: complex-analysis, math-history

I am looking for a paper that gives a non-brief, non-concise, step-by-step, nothing-taken-for-granted proof of the result that the RZF cannot have any zeros on the line $\text{Re}(z)=1$.  Certainly there must be a survey paper or something written at the level of an advanced undergraduate but I have not found one.  If anyone knows a citation, I would like to see it.  Thanks.

Comment: Apostol's textbook on Analytic Number Theory could be what you want.

Comment: Also we like thisone https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/ant/main.pdf but you to study the PNT you should get as many texts as you can. After the zero-free region you'll need a Tauberian theorem to prove the PNT.

Comment: Since you seem to be fond of non-brief and non-concise proofs, perhaps you could write *Riemann zeta function* instead of RZF.